# imageSmoothingEnabled sometimes doesn't work when drawing canvas on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I notice some weird interaction between clearRect, fillRect and drawImage. It's best explained by a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/tf950zpd/13/
Code:

```
const c1 = document.getElementById("a").getContext("2d");
const c2 = document.getElementById("b").getContext("2d");
c1.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
c2.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
c1.fillStyle = "white";
c1.fillRect(0,0,2,2);
c1.fillStyle = "black";
c1.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
c1.fillRect(1,1,1,1);

document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
    c1.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
}
document.getElementById("b2").onclick = function() {
  c2.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    c2.drawImage(c1.canvas, 0,0,2,2,0,0,100,100);
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="banner-message">
<button id="b1">
  draw A
</button>
<button id="b2">
  draw B
</button>
<canvas id="a" width="2" height="2"></canvas>
<canvas id="b" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

The expectation is that the smoothing is always disabled when I click "draw B".

If you click draw B twice, it has smoothing disabled for the first time, but smoothing enabled for the second time.
If you click "draw A", and then "draw B", it works again for once, but still has smoothing enabled for the second time.

My question is why it doesn't work as expected and how do I fix it?

Comment: What browser and OS are you experiencing this on? Is your monitor an "high-res" monitor? Does the same happen if you do `c2.getImageData(0,0,1,1);` before the call to `c2.drawImage`?

Comment: I'm currently using chrome os. I noticed that it works on my windows chrome and linux chrome. Adding "c2.getImageData(0,0,1,1);" fixes it as well. So I guess it's probably a bug in chrome os.

Comment: Yes that's a bug with Hardware acceleration. Please let them know at https://crbug.com and include as many details about your config as you can.